# $.jgrid.nav in jqgrid for jquery

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, navigator

I have two different jqGrids in the same page.
In the first grid I've set custom functions for the add and edit buttons in the navigator bar, using the following code:

```
$.jgrid.nav.addfunc = 
                    function() {
                         $('#btninsreset').click();
                    };
$.jgrid.nav.editfunc =
                    function(id) {
                        editUscita(id);
                    };
```

In the second grid I'd like to have the default behaviour, but I get the same seetings as the first grid instead.
How may I reset the navigator to the default settings for the second jqgrid?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting of `$.jgrid.nav.addfunc` change the global settings, so you can not use this if you want to have two jqGrids on the same page. The easiest way to solve the problem is setting of addfunc and editfunc as parameters of the first grid:

```
jQuery('#grid1').jqGrid({
    // ...
    '#pager1'
}).jqGrid ('navGrid', '#pager1', {
                                  addfunc: function() {$('#btninsreset').click();},
                                  editfunc: function(id) {editUscita(id);}
                                 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'v done it: I simply have to set $.jgrid.nav.addfunc = null;

Comment: Because of the reasons that Oleg mention above. Overwriting a global function to null is asking for trouble.